# Estimate distribution of a composite variable

Tags: probability-theory, randomness, sampling

Suppose I have N sets of numbers (10 numbers per set) {a1, ....., a10}. I form a sum by taking one number at random from each set. SUM = num from set 1 +......+ num from set N. If I do this a large number of times I will generate a large number of different values for the SUM variable. How can I estimate the distribution of the SUM values (P10, P50, P90 etc.)?

Comment: First of all, you haven't defined a distribution, but I'm assuming that you're picking the number uniformly and independently. Second, what do you mean by "estimate the distribution of `Sum`"? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions).

For instance, write the generating function for each set, then multiply the generating functions; this gives you the generating function for the distribution of the sum.

This gives you the exact distribution (which is even better than an approximation!).

Comment: D.W. In order to find the exact distribution of the values of SUM would I not have to evaluate all possible combinations of the summed values/

Comment: @DavidWilkinson, no, you would not.  My answer describes how to do it, *without* evaluating all combinations.  I recommend you read about convolutions and generating functions, if you're not already familiar with the subject, as they solve exactly this problem in an elegant, efficient way.