# Expected value of the remainder when a random variable is divided by a number

Tags: python

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be integers selected from the set $\{1,2,\cdots, 100\}$ uniformly and at random with replacement. Let $M=a+2b+4c+8d+16e+32f$. What is the expected value of the remainder when $M$ is divided by $64$?

I was trying to write a python code to calculate the answer. Let $f(x)$ be the remainder when $x$ is divided by $64$, then the desired number is
$$E(f(M))=\sum_{k=1}^{100}f(M)\cdot \frac{1}{100}.$$

Here is my code:

```
S=0
for k in list(range(1,101)):
  S += ((k+2*k+4*k+8*k+16*k+32*k)%64)/100
print('E(M mod 64)= ', S)
```

The output is  `E(M mod 64)=  36.540000000000006`. But the answer should be $31.5$. What is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your code, `a=b=c=d=e=f`, while in the statement they are independent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#Multiplication, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/42422/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/117865/755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives the wrong answer because you got 6 random variables instead of one, but you are computing esxected value as if you have only one random variable. Let me put this on maths:
Let $f$ be the remainder by 64 for $M$, then $f$ is a function of the random variables $a,b,c,d,e,f$, therefore
$$Ef(M)=\displaystyle \sum_a\sum_b\ldots\sum_e\sum_ff(M)P(a,b,c,d,e,f)$$
Since your selection is uniform with replacement, $P(a,b,c,d,e,f)=1/100^6$. Now you need to rewrite your code.

Comment: I count 6 random variables.

Comment: Yeah, a small mistake since i set the expectation for 6 r.v, thanks.